# .config file read. Using ConfigRead

Tags: nsis

Using `$ {ConfigRead} "[File]" "[Entry]"$ var`

config file infomation =

```
(?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?)
(configuration)
    (appSettings)
        (add key="name" value="gyujin" /)
        (add key="age" value="30" /)
    (/appSettings)
(/configuration)
```

( == <       ////////            ) == >

I want to get the value of "name"...
i don't know "[Entry]" value...
Please help me !

Comment: Why have you not tried the XML plug-ins?

Answer (score 0):

${ConfigRead} is intended to read values from ini like files (which is default Windows format for configuration).

It will not work with your .xml file/structure.

Comment: Not actually a answer?